# How to Handle HTML Fields with Same Name in Multiple Locations

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a non-commercial web app constructed using straight HTML, PHP, and Javascript and using Dynamic Drive's Tab Content code.  The app lets me manage the books in our home library and on my ereader.

I am trying to consolidate some code into an includeable module - specifically, the fields and code to select an author's name by first asking the user to choose the first letter of the last name to limit the selection list.  JS AJAX code calls a PHP module to populate the name selection list from the user's choice.  This has worked fine in one location when the other locations/tabs use a standard selection list populated by PHP code but this list is extensive due to the number of authors.  I decided to try and use a common module to make this process identical whether the user is looking to mark a book as read, to find books, or to find if a book has been read.

After modifying three separate locations in the same HTML module (different tabs identified by different 'div's), when I try to select an author in say, the 'find a book' tab/code section, the selection list of names in the first instance is filled always.  I suspect that it has to do with the name assigned to that selection list.

Is there any way for me to use this common code three places in the same HTML module/file through an 'include' statement and have the JS and PHP code operate on the selection field in that section/tab?  I am simply trying to avoid duplicating the code three times.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I no longer need an answer to this question.  After posting it, I realized that since I'm using an HTML/CSS/JS package that let's me set up tabs for the various sub-apps of my main app and all of this is in one HTML file, I would have to name each instance of a variable by a different name.

I have restructured the code into multiple HTML/PHP files.  I can now create common code for doing the same thing in multiple tasks (aka, HTML files/pages).  It has worked out well.

Thanks for any thought anyone has offered on this.